# Обращение к БД из фрагмента

Tags: android, java, база-данных

не могу достучаться до БД из фрагмента

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
        Log.i("LOG_Fragemnt ", "ROW ");

      DataBase  sqh = new DataBase(getActivity());
```

Из активити я передаю ему контекст и работает, но не работает а в фрагменте,

Выводит ошибку

> 12-18 05:22:37.983
> 4052-4052/com.example.eldos.callreport
> E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION:
> main Process:
> com.example.eldos.callreport, PID:
> 4052 java.lang.NullPointerException

Что не так делаю?

Comment: Нужно больше инфы. В каком конкретно месте падает. Привести больше кода, если необходимо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так работает

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("setAdaperToListView"));
    sqh = new DataBase(getActivity());
    sqdb = sqh.getWritableDatabase();
    final View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2,null);
    return content;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

в `onActivityCreated` ***обязательно*** первым методом должен быть вызван

```
super.onActivityCreated();
```

Comment: Нет, не обязательно первым, можно сделать в самом конце метода вызов, но надо это осознавать.

Comment: @Andreich, да, вы правы, я неправильно выразился.